# How to link a javascript bootstrap method in grails

Tags: javascript, grails

I am trying to create a dropdown menu taken straight from bootstrap website

however it seems that I am having problem calling through the javascript method `$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown()`

If you are familiar with grails are you able to tell if I have it right or not ?
I don't know if I am calling it through the correct tags.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html lang="en" class="no-js ie6"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html lang="en" class="no-js ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html lang="en" class="no-js ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html lang="en" class="no-js ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html lang="en" class="no-js"><!--<![endif]-->
    <head>
        <asset:stylesheet src="main.css"/>
        <asset:stylesheet src="bootstrap.min.css"/>
        <asset:javascript src="bootstrap.min.js"/>
        <g:layoutHead/>
    </head>
    <body class="container">



<!-- Single button -->
<g:javascript>
$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown()
</g:javascript>
<h1>Admin </h1>
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    upload <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: jQuery should be added before adding bootstrap. [Bootstrap depends on it](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#js-overview). Have a look at plugin dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Bootstrap** depends on **jQuery** so download  `jquery.min.js` and add :

```
<asset:javascript src="jquery.min.js"/>
```

to your head like this:

```
<head>
        <asset:javascript src="jquery.min.js"/>
        <asset:stylesheet src="main.css"/>
        <asset:stylesheet src="bootstrap.min.css"/>
        <asset:javascript src="bootstrap.min.js"/>
        <g:layoutHead/>
</head>
```